# Extending Magento2 class

Tags: magento2

I am trying to extend a Magento2 class **`Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery`**. This is because I want to add videos to products and that only works if I add a line of code in an array. Because this is a Magento class it gets overwritten at every update so I am trying to extend/overwrite it but for some reason, it does not want to work. I don't see the module if I run

```
bin/magento module:status
```

> **di.xml** app/code/Headline/ProductVideo/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery"
                type="Headline\ProductVideo\Block\Product\View\Gallery"></preference>
</config>
```

> **module.xml** app/code/Headline/ProductVideo/etc

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Headline_ProductVideo" setup_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
             <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> **registration.php** app/code/Headline/ProductVideo

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Headline_ProductVideo',
    __DIR__
);
```

> **Gallery.php** app/code/Headline/ProductVideo/Block/Product/View

```
<?php

namespace Headline\ProductVideo\Block\Product\View;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image;

class Gallery extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Gallery
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils $arrayUtils
     * @param EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayUtils $arrayUtils,
        EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $arrayUtils, $jsonEncoder,$data);
    }

    public function getGalleryImages()
    {
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
        if ($images instanceof \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection) {
            foreach ($images as $image) {
                /* @var \Magento\Framework\DataObject $image */
                $image->setData(
                    'small_image_url',
                    $this->_imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_small')
                        ->setImageFile($image->getFile())
                        ->getUrl()
                );
                $image->setData(
                    'medium_image_url',
                    $this->_imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_medium_no_frame')
                        ->setImageFile($image->getFile())
                        ->getUrl()
                );
                $image->setData(
                    'large_image_url',
                    $this->_imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_large_no_frame')
                        ->setImageFile($image->getFile())
                        ->getUrl()
                );
            }
        }

        return $images;
    }

    /**
     * Return magnifier options
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMagnifier()
    {
        return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($this->getVar('magnifier'));
    }

    /**
     * Return breakpoints options
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBreakpoints()
    {
        return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($this->getVar('breakpoints'));
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve product images in JSON format
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGalleryImagesJson()
    {
        die();
        $imagesItems = [];
        foreach ($this->getGalleryImages() as $image) {
            $imagesItems[] = [
                'thumb' => $image->getData('small_image_url'),
                'img' => $image->getData('medium_image_url'),
                'full' => $image->getData('large_image_url'),
                'caption' => ($image->getLabel() ?: $this->getProduct()->getName()),
                'position' => $image->getPosition(),
                'isMain' => $this->isMainImage($image),
                'type' => str_replace('external-', '', $image->getMediaType()),
                'videoUrl' => $image->getVideoUrl(),
                'video' => $image->getVideoUrl(), //video fix
            ];
        }
        if (empty($imagesItems)) {
            $imagesItems[] = [
                'thumb' => $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('thumbnail'),
                'img' => $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image'),
                'full' => $this->_imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image'),
                'caption' => '',
                'position' => '0',
                'isMain' => true,
                'type' => 'image',
                'videoUrl' => null,
            ];
        }
        return json_encode($imagesItems);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve gallery url
     *
     * @param null|\Magento\Framework\DataObject $image
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGalleryUrl($image = null)
    {
        $params = ['id' => $this->getProduct()->getId()];
        if ($image) {
            $params['image'] = $image->getValueId();
        }
        return $this->getUrl('catalog/product/gallery', $params);
    }

    /**
     * Is product main image
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $image
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isMainImage($image)
    {
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        return $product->getImage() == $image->getFile();
    }

    /**
     * @param string $imageId
     * @param string $attributeName
     * @param string $default
     * @return string
     */
    public function getImageAttribute($imageId, $attributeName, $default = null)
    {
        $attributes =
            $this->getConfigView()->getMediaAttributes('Magento_Catalog', Image::MEDIA_TYPE_CONFIG_NODE, $imageId);
        return $attributes[$attributeName] ?? $default;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve config view
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Config\View
     */
    private function getConfigView()
    {
        if (!$this->configView) {
            $this->configView = $this->_viewConfig->getViewConfig();
        }
        return $this->configView;
    }
}
```

In `Headline\ProductVideo\Block\Product\View\Gallery` I have the same code as the original file but added the line of code in the array. In the original block classes, I changed the path to the Gallery.php file. I changed that in **`catalog_product_view_config.xml`** and **`catalog_product_view_2-cols`**

Answer (score 0):

module.xml should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Headline_ProductVideo" setup_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

But otherwise looks good.

Just to confirm you should clear cache (as you've introduced new XML) and run upgrade.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

If that still doesn't work try

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: I tried your version of module.xml but without luck. I ran the following commands:
 `#!/bin/bash
bin/magento setup:upgrade;
bin/magento setup:di:compile;
cd tools && gulp styles;
cd ..;
bin/magento cache:clean;`

I still don't see the module when I run bin/magento module:status

Comment: I added Gallery.php code. Maybe it helps